# Creating Node Package with Angular2 and Webpackage

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, webpack

I am building a large application with multiple projects so i want to put some Angular2 components in an extra module, that gets shared between all of the modules.

Since i am using webpack in my projects it would be nice to use the adavantages in the node module, but the generated output is not really useable.

The reason why i am trying to use webpack is to take advantage of the loaders webpack provides. I want to seperate the template and styles in different files.

Is there a way to use webpack to render my angular2 components in a way where i can use them as a node_module in a different project?

Answer (score 0):

By default Webpack outputs a bundle for the browser. If you want your code to be usable in another project, you can use `output.library` and `output.libraryTarget` in your Webpack configuration. An example:

```
output: {
    library: 'MyComponentName', // Your component / library name
    libraryTarget: 'umd', // Or 'commonjs2', 'var', ...
}
```

This will result in a bundle you can import in the browser or with any module system that supports AMD or CommonJS2 (like Webpack, Browserify, RequireJS, ...).

More information is available [in the Webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library) for these two options.

Bonus:

If you do not set the `output.library` option, all exported properties of your main bundle will be exported. This only has effect for bundlers/browsers that do not use AMD or CommonJS. For example:

entrypoint.js:

```
module.exports = {
    firstExport: 1,
    secondExport: 2,
};
```

With `output.library` set to `MyLibrary`, this will happen in a browser:

```
var MyLibrary = { firstExport: 1, secondExport: 2 };
```

Without `output.library`, it looks like this:

```
var firstExport = 1;
var secondExport = 2;
```